# Is there a word for a person whose work is primarily cognitive, not pragmatic, and who builds his career/reputation this way?

Tags: single-word-requests, personality

Is there a word for a person whose work is primarily cognitive, not pragmatic, and who builds his career/reputation this way?

It doesn't need to have a negative connotation. Here is an example person: extremely popular on twitter, often invited to speak (paid), verbose / wax poetic, very conceptual, very popular external to organization but not understood locally, focuses work externally but does not have significant local work.

Comment: Your question is confusing. It is not clear what you mean by "local" and "external." But you may want ***Pop scientist*** or ***pop philosopher*** or ***pop intellectual***.

Comment: How is thinking not pragmatic??

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for **intellectual**. It describes a person who functions mostly in the realm of the intellect (cognition) and carries an implication of being not pragmatic.

Comment: Hahahahaha! Good one, DJ! But, did you mean to write, "...an implication of not being pragmatic"? :-) +1

Comment: @MarkHubbard Works either way round for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, "thoughtleader" tends to be used to describe such a person. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_leader